# exec: Вызов утилиты с помощью execve и запрет логирования

Tags: c

Есть системная утилита, которая при какой - либо ошибке, пишет в журналы `/var/log`
Возможно ли запретить этой утилите писать в журналы ? Если её запуск выглядит так:

```
execve("/path/to/file", NULL, NULL);
```

Я пытался использовать `closelog()` перед запуском `execve`, но безуспешно, прога всё равно спамит в лог. Функции, которые пишут в лог программой `"/path/to/file"` называются `openlog` / `syslog`

Comment: обратитесь к документации на эту утилиту, возможно там есть режим foreground. openlog / syslog можно убить написав собственную реализацию библиотеки syslog

Comment: @eri, а что, тоже вариант, спасибо!

Comment: обычно системные утилиты настолько простые что их проще переписать с нуля чем заниматься подпроцессами...

Comment: а не хочешь настроить свой syslog, чтобы он просто не сохранял логи от этой программы?

Comment: Посмотрите man syslog, man 5 syslog.conf (или м.б. у вас man 5 rsyslog.conf) чтобы попробовать настроить логгинг этой конкретной утилиты